# Non-recursive find on linux

Tags: linux, backup, unix, bash, find

I am trying to find all directories that are directly inside the current directory and older than a specific age. The trick is, I only want to consider the age of the immediate descendants of the current directory, and not search through them recursively.

Usage example is for daily backups of files - a new directory is created every day, but the files placed inside that directory keep their timestamps and are often older. I want to be able to clean up old backups without deleting the old files in more recent snapshots.

It looks like `find` may not be able to do this, what unix tool (or a combination of them) do you recommend?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can you `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` with your modified/accessed/changed attribute search of choice, i.e.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mtime 4
```

for 4 days.

Don't forget to exclude the `.` and `..` results that `find` returns.

[Useful link](http://www.thelinuxlink.net/lvlinux/resources/commands/find.html) to many `find` examples.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that option (maxdepth) before, but used it incorrectly. Now this works!

Comment: I think it would be -mtime +4 for older than 4 days rather than exactly 4 days.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` options.

Answer (score 1):

`find` will work fine. Just add `-maxdepth 1`